# Changing type of Data Frame cells without loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Sometimes, data is not in the format we wish it to be. Python offers ways to deal with this (such as int() and str()), but solutions for Data Frames are not trivial.

For instance, let us generate a Data Frame of 5 datetime observations:

```
import pandas
from datetime import datetime

datelist = pd.date_range(datetime.today(), periods=5).tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame (datelist, columns = ['A'])
```

[image]

Our goal is to convert this datetime data into the date format.

First, we may try

```
df['A'] = df['A'].datetime.date()
```

For which we will get an Attribute Error: 'Series' object has not attribute 'date'. An option, then, would be to create a loop to change each cell at a time, but, according to Pandas documentation, we should never change something we are iterating over (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html). How could we, then, solve this problem?

Comment: `df['A'] = df['A'].dt.floor('D')`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.dt` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) *for datetimelike properties of the Series values*:

```
df.A.dt.date

# 0    2021-02-23
# 1    2021-02-24
# 2    2021-02-25
# 3    2021-02-26
# 4    2021-02-27
# Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: You answer is good, but actually I am looking for something more general. What if data is string, for instance? Is there an exhaustive list of acessors we can use?

Comment: In that case, you will need to convert your column to datetime first. `pd.to_datetime(df.A).dt.date`.